# How to properly trim whitespaces from a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, unicode

The JDK's [String.trim()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) method is pretty naive, and only removes ascii control characters.

Apache Commons' [StringUtils.strip()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#strip(java.lang.String)) is slightly better, but uses the JDK's [Character.isWhitespace()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)), which [doesn't recognize non-breaking space as whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060570/why-is-non-breaking-space-not-a-whitespace-character-in-java).

So what would be the most complete, Unicode-compatible, safe and proper way to trim a string in Java?

And incidentally, is there a better library than `commons-lang` that I should be using for this sort of stuff?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Google has made [guava-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries) available recently. It [may have](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.java#920) what you are looking for:

```
CharMatcher.inRange('\0', ' ').trimFrom(str)
```

is equivalent to String.trim(), but you can customize what to trim, refer to the JavaDoc.

For instance, it has [its own definition of WHITESPACE](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.java#48) which differs from the JDK and is defined according to the latest Unicode standard, so what you need can be written as:

```
CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.trimFrom(str)
```

Comment: Tip: [`trimAndCollapseFrom`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#trimAndCollapseFrom(java.lang.CharSequence,%20char)) trims the outside of the string while also replacing duplicate values inside the string.

Answer (score 8):

I swear I only saw this after I posted the question: Google just released [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), a library of core Java utilities.

I haven't tried this yet, but from what I can tell, this is fully Unicode compliant:

```
String s = "  \t testing \u00a0"
s = CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.trimFrom(s);
```

Comment: Haha, I've provided the same answer just 5 minutes earlier, but then edited it to include the exact code you need to use, and just then saw your comment that you found it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It's really hard to define what constitutes white spaces. Sometimes I use non-breakable spaces just to make sure it doesn't get stripped. So it will be hard to find a library to do exactly what you want.

I use my own trim() if I want trim every white space. Here is the function I use to check for white spaces,

```
  public static boolean isWhitespace (int ch)
  {
    if (ch == ' ' || (ch >= 0x9 && ch <= 0xD))
      return true;
    if (ch < 0x85) // short-circuit optimization.
      return false;
    if (ch == 0x85 || ch == 0xA0 || ch == 0x1680 || ch == 0x180E)
      return true;
    if (ch < 0x2000 || ch > 0x3000)
      return false;
    return ch <= 0x200A || ch == 0x2028 || ch == 0x2029
      || ch == 0x202F || ch == 0x205F || ch == 0x3000;
  }
```

Comment: ZZ Coder -- you say, "it will be hard to find a library to do exactly what you want."  Not true!

Say you want to match all whitespace _except_ a \u00a0 (non-breaking space).  Easy:

CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.and(CharMatcher.isNot('\u00a0')).trimFrom(input)

Comment: @KevinBourrillion just wanted to send over a big "thanks" for `CharMatcher.WHITESPACE`. `String#trim()` fails so hard with Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

I've always found `trim` to work pretty well for almost every scenario.

However, if you really want to include more characters, you can edit the [`strip`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java.html) method from `commons-lang` to include not only the test for `Character.isWhitespace`, but also for **`Character.isSpaceChar`** which *seems* to be what's missing. Namely, the following lines at `stripStart` and `stripEnd`, respectively:

- `while ((start != strLen) && Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(start)))`
- `while ((end != 0) && Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(end - 1)))`

Answer (score 0):

I did little changes on java's trim() method and it supports non-ascii characters.This method runs faster than most of the implementations.

```
public static String trimAdvanced(String value) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(value);

        int strLength = value.length();
        int len = value.length();
        int st = 0;
        char[] val = value.toCharArray();

        if (strLength == 0) {
            return "";
        }

        while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ') || (val[st] == '\u00A0')) {
            st++;
            if (st == strLength) {
                break;
            }
        }
        while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ') || (val[len - 1] == '\u00A0')) {
            len--;
            if (len == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }


        return (st > len) ? "" : ((st > 0) || (len < strLength)) ? value.substring(st, len) : value;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This handles Unicode characters and doesn't require extra libraries:

```
String trimmed = original.replaceAll ("^\\p{IsWhite_Space}+|\\p{IsWhite_Space}+$", "");
```

A slight snag is that there are some related whitespace characters without Unicode character property "WSpace=Y" which are listed in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character). These probably won't cause a problem, but you can easy add them to the character class too.

Using [almson-regex](https://github.com/almson/almson-regex) the regex will look like:

```
String trimmed = original.replaceAll (either (START_BOUNDARY + oneOrMore (WHITESPACE), oneOrMore (WHITESPACE) + END BOUNDARY), "");
```

and include the more relevant of the non-Unicode whitespace.