# Mysql inserts the data as unknown values java

Tags: java

Hello i am using prepared statement to insert the values into mysql.

I am facing an issue in an string which is inserting as `"c2a054656e6e6973c2a0"` for value `" Tennis "` and i tried to use trim to trim the whitespace in front of the "Tennis" it did not work .From this question [Why trim is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728625/why-trim-is-not-working) i tried using the solution `poNumber.replace(String.valueOf((char) 160), " ").trim();` and it worked. can any one give solution for this?

SAMPLE CODE

```
CREATE TABLE `news1` (
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_title` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `article_subcategory` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;
```

//Sample category will be "Home » Tennis"

```
 String category = item.getArticle_category();
                String categoryArray[] = category.split("»");
                preparedStatement = connect
                        .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO news1 VALUES(default,?,?)");
                System.out.println(categoryArray[2].replace(String.valueOf((char) 160), " ")
                        .trim());
                preparedStatement.setString(1, item.getArticle_title());
                preparedStatement.setString(2, categoryArray[2]);
```

Comment: What's the question here? You seem to have found the solution for your `trim` problem, so what are you still confused about?

Comment: Yes i found the solution for trim but the string is inserted as "c2a054656e6e6973c2a0" in mysql that is the real problem

Comment: What charset of your table in mySql?

Comment: can you show a sample of your code?

Comment: String temp = categoryArray[2].replace(String.valueOf((char) 160), " ")
                        .trim(); and use temp in preparedStatement.setString(2, temp);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing this `categoryArray[2].replace(String.valueOf((char) 160), " ") .trim()` in sys out but you do `preparedStatement.setString(2, categoryArray[2]);` in your statement

```
String temp = categoryArray[2].replace(String.valueOf((char) 160), " ") .trim(); 
System.out.println(temp);
```

and use temp in

```
preparedStatement.setString(2, temp);
```

Comment: No. i am scrapping data from an website which has the char "»" and split it and use it in db while making ans SYSOUT it works it prints the string while inserting it fails