# Can't trim() or replaceAll() a strange whitespace

Tags: java, regex

Program reads a list of domains from a text-file and check via Regex if the domain is valid. 
The problem is that there is some kind of strange whitespace at the end of some domains, which I can't delete. The parsing problems occurs only when there is this strange whitespace. My Regex is totally fine(!!! :-)

I tried `trim()` and `replaceAll("\\s", "")` both can't work. How can I figure out what kind of strange Char that could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what is it? Can you display it's hex value?

Comment: `replaceAll("\s", "")` wouldn't compile unless you escaped the backslash, but I digress.  You'd be best to show us the regex you're using and the byte structure of the string you're having trouble with (`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(troubleString.toCharArray));`).

Comment: "there is some kind of strange whitespace at the end of some domains" - well, without a way to reproduce, I doubt that anyone will be able to help you...

Comment: `System.out.println(" a  b   c    d".replaceAll("\\s", ""));` works for me.

Comment: @Crayl No problem, glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Used this method to create a hex representation of that String:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18261315/558559

Turns out that the whitespace is a "no-break space", described here:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm

And to delete it I had to this solution:

```
stringWithStrangeWhiteSpace = stringWithStrangeWhiteSpace.replace(String.valueOf((char) 160), " ").trim();
```

Described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4728647/558559

I have no idea what I did there :D