# Groovy XmlSlurper with TagSoup and non-breaking space values

Tags: java, string, groovy, xmlslurper, tag-soup

I'm parsing some HTML4 with Groovy's `XmlSlurper` backed by a tagsoup `Parser`.

I'm getting the `text()` of a node successfully, but HTML `&nbsp;` spaces are giving me some difficulty when trying to test for equality with another value. Specifically, `.trim()` does not actually trim the string of all whitespace.  It appears to me that the characters on either side of the value are whitespace (see code below) but `String.trim()` isn't trimming the way I'd expect.  As can be seen from the code sample, `Character.isSpaceChar()` for the first character in the string is determined to be a space character.

**Why is `String.trim()` not trimming this value that I've obtained from `XmlSlurper`?**

```
@Grab('org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2.1')
import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser

def html = '''
<html>
<body>
<span id="interested">&nbsp;hello&nbsp;</span>
</body>
</html>
'''

def slurper = new XmlSlurper(new Parser() )
def document = slurper.parseText(html)

def value = document.'**'.find { it['@id'] == 'interested' }.text()

println "value=[${value}]"
println "first char isWhitespace? ${Character.isWhitespace(value.charAt(0))}"
println "first char isSpaceChar? ${Character.isSpaceChar(value.charAt(0))}"
assert 'hello' == value.trim()
```

Yields:

```
value=[ hello ]
first char isWhitespace? false
first char isSpaceChar? true
Exception thrown

Assertion failed: 

assert 'hello' == value.trim()
               |  |     |
               |  |      hello 
               |   hello 
               false
```

I'm using `Groovy Version: 2.3.6 JVM: 1.8.0 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X`

Comment: In this particular example `trim()` didn't remove whitespaces.

Comment: That's precisely the question - why isn't it trimming whitespace (or at least a known `isSpaceChar()`) ?

Comment: you can also use `\p{javaSpaceChar}` in a regexp to get rid of lots of whitespacy junk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here You have corrected example:

```
@Grab('org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2.1')
import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser

def html = '''
<html>
<body>
<span id="interested">&nbsp;hello&nbsp;</span>
</body>
</html>
'''

def slurper = new XmlSlurper(new Parser() )
def document = slurper.parseText(html)

def value = document.'**'.find { it['@id'] == 'interested' }.text()

println "value=[${value}]"
println "first char isWhitespace? ${Character.isWhitespace(value.charAt(0))}"
println "first char isSpaceChar? ${Character.isSpaceChar(value.charAt(0))}"
value = value.trim()
println "first char isWhitespace? ${Character.isWhitespace(value.charAt(0))}"
println "first char isSpaceChar? ${Character.isSpaceChar(value.charAt(0))}"
assert 'hello' == value.replaceAll(String.valueOf((char) 160), " ").trim()
```

And explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728625/why-trim-is-not-working) (space vs non-breaking space).

Comment: OK - thank you. I'm re-reading [Character.isWhitespace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-int-) javadocs - which clearly explain that `A character is a Java whitespace character if and only if it satisfies one of the following criteria:
It is a Unicode space character (SPACE_SEPARATOR, LINE_SEPARATOR, or PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR) but is not also a non-breaking space ('\u00A0', '\u2007', '\u202F').`  I had missed that. Thanks!