# Converting a String with spaces to an Integer in java

Tags: java, string, integer

I'm trying to convert a String variable into an integer, only the String looks like this (for example):

```
String string = " 12";
```

And so the String has a space in front of it. Now the String variable is being read from a .txt file which is why I'm having the issue of having the space in front of it. I need to convert the variable into an int, but when I try:

```
int integer = Integer.parseInt(string);
```

to pass the String into an integer, it compiles but I get an error when trying to run the program, since there is white space as part of the String.

Is there a way to pass a String of numbers with a space in front of it into an int? Would .trim work? And if so, how would I use that? (I'm not very familiar with .trim, I'm still learning!!) I appreciate the help! ^_^

Comment: I understand you are learning, but if you can code and run this code why can't you check if .trim() would work?

Comment: If the values are being read from a file, you should really be using `Scanner`'s `nextInt()` method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Would .trim work? And if so, how would I use that?

Yes,  `trim()` will work, it will remove leading and trailing spaces from `String`,

```
int integer = Integer.parseInt(string.trim());
```

Comment: This is a really good answer. It has one drawback though. It's not Unicode-aware.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437933/how-to-properly-trim-whitespaces-from-a-string-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266582/difference-between-string-trim-and-strip-methods-in-java-11

Answer (score 7):

Use the string trim function in Java to first get a string without the spaces, then parse it...

1.) **Remove spaces with trim** ... [String#trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

```
String stringWithoutSpace = string.trim();
```

2.) **Parse the string without spaces** ... [Integer#parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

```
int integer = Integer.parseInt(stringWithoutSpace);
```

3.) **Do everything above in one step** ...

```
int integer = Integer.parseInt(string.trim());
```

Answer (score 6):

The string split() method works well if you have a string of multiple numbers separated by spaces.

```
String numbers = "1 23 456";
String[] numbersArray = numbers.split(" "); // splitting string by spaces
System.out.println(numbersArray.toString());
// output ["1","23","456"]
```

Then you can use Integer.parseInt() on each index of the array. 
Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

If you using Java 11, you can use the `String::strip` method.  For example:

```
int integer = Integer.parseInt(string.strip());
```

The `strip()` method is similar to `trim()` but uses `Character.isWhitespace(int)` to resolve spaces.  (The `Character.isWhitespace(int)` method is Unicode-aware.)

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that your code does not throw `NumberFormatException` or even `NullPointerException`, when you get number from user, use apache common classes:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils;
.....
// '1' is the default value which is returned when the string can not be converted to int
// The StringUtils.trimToEmpty do both left and right trim
int number = NumberUtils.toInt(StringUtils.trimToEmpty( "  12 ",1)) = 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove blank character before convert the string

```
int integer = Integer.parseInt(string.trim());
```

then, use parseInt or valueOf to convert the string
for more information，please refer [convert string to int](https://www.asenview.com/convert-string-to-int-in-java/)