# Difference between String trim() and strip() methods in Java 11

Tags: java, string, trim, strip, java-11

Among other changes, JDK 11 introduces 6 new methods for java.lang.String class:

- `repeat(int)` - Repeats the String as many times as provided by the `int` parameter
- `lines()` - Uses a Spliterator to lazily provide lines from the source string
- `isBlank()` - Indicates if the String is empty or contains only white space characters
- `stripLeading()` - Removes the white space from the beginning
- `stripTrailing()` - Removes the white space from the end
- **`strip()`** - Removes the white space from both, beginning and the end of string

In particular, `strip()` looks very similar to `trim()`. As per [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/applying-new-jdk-11-string-methods) `strip*()` methods are designed to:

> The String.strip(), String.stripLeading(), and String.stripTrailing()
>   methods trim white space [as determined by Character.isWhiteSpace()]
>   off either the front, back, or both front and back of the targeted
>   String.

`String.trim()` JavaDoc states:

```
/**
  * Returns a string whose value is this string, with any leading and trailing
  * whitespace removed.
  * ...
  */
```

Which is almost identical to the quote above.

What exactly the difference between `String.trim()` and `String.strip()` since Java 11?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

In short: `strip()` is "Unicode-aware" evolution of `trim()`. Meaning `trim()` removes only characters <= U+0020 (space); `strip()` removes all Unicode whitespace characters (but not all control characters, such as \0)

[CSR : JDK-8200378](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8200378)

> **Problem**

String::trim has existed from early days of Java when Unicode

> had not fully evolved to the standard we widely use today.
>
> The definition of space used by String::trim is any code point less
> than or equal to the space code point (\u0020), commonly referred to
> as ASCII or ISO control characters.
>
> Unicode-aware trimming routines should use
> Character::isWhitespace(int).
>
> Additionally, developers have not been able to specifically remove
> indentation white space or to specifically remove trailing white
> space.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Introduce trimming methods that are Unicode white space aware
> and provide additional control of leading only or trailing only.

A common characteristic of these new methods is that they use a different (newer) definition of "whitespace" than did old methods such as `String.trim()`. Bug [JDK-8200373](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8200373).

> The current JavaDoc for String::trim does not make it clear which
> definition of "space" is being used in the code. With additional
> trimming methods coming in the near future that use a different
> definition of space, clarification is imperative. String::trim uses
> the definition of space as any codepoint that is less than or equal to
> the space character codepoint (\u0020.) Newer trimming methods will
> use the definition of (white) space as any codepoint that returns true
> when passed to the Character::isWhitespace predicate.

The method `isWhitespace(char)` was added to `Character` with JDK 1.1, but the method `isWhitespace(int)` was not introduced to the `Character` class until JDK 1.5. The latter method (the one accepting a parameter of type `int`) was added to support supplementary characters. The Javadoc comments for the `Character` class define supplementary characters (typically modeled with int-based "code point") versus BMP characters (typically modeled with single character):

> The set of characters from U+0000 to U+FFFF is sometimes referred to
> as the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). Characters whose code points
> are greater than U+FFFF are called supplementary characters. The Java
> platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays and in the
> String and StringBuffer classes. In this representation, supplementary
> characters are represented as a pair of char values ... A char value,
> therefore, represents Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) code points,
> including the surrogate code points, or code units of the UTF-16
> encoding. An int value represents all Unicode code points, including
> supplementary code points. ... The methods that only accept a char
> value cannot support supplementary characters. ... The methods that
> accept an int value support all Unicode characters, including
> supplementary characters.

OpenJDK [Changeset](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/92560438d306).

---

Benchmark comparison between `trim()` and `strip()` - [Why is String.strip() 5 times faster than String.trim() for blank string In Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640184/why-is-string-strip-5-times-faster-than-string-trim-for-blank-string-in-java)

Comment: Interesting that symbol '\u0000' is not deleted by strip, but deleted by trim.

Comment: Why not upgrade trim() itself, instead of creating a new method? It would've worked on existing applications without any developer intervention? Or is that the very reason they decided to create new method?

Comment: @human Because a big part of the Java ethos is to maximize backwards-compatibility. Changing the behavior of a method like `String::trim` would bring unwelcome surprises to existing codebases.

Comment: Is strip's universe of characters a superset of trim's universe of characters? In other words does strip strip more than trim trims?

Comment: apparently trim's set of characters are not a subset of strip's one, since symbol '\u0000' is not deleted by strip, but deleted by trim :-/ ...

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov could you please update the "In short" statement. As mentioned by CHEM_Eugene `strip` does not remove all control characters. The current answer might make developers believe they can 'update' their code to use `strip`, but in reality they might be removing control character sanitization by accident this way. Could you please change it to: "In short: `trim` removes only characters <= U+0020 (space); `strip` removes all Unicode whitespace characters (but not all control characters, such as `\0`)" (or similar)

Answer (score 60):

Here is a unit-test that illustrates the answer by @MikhailKholodkov, using Java 11.

(Note that [`\u2000`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) is above `\u0020` and not considered whitespace by `trim()`)

```
public class StringTestCase {
    @Test
    public void testSame() {
        String s = "\t abc \n";

        assertEquals("abc", s.trim());
        assertEquals("abc", s.strip());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDifferent() {
        Character c = '\u2000';
        String s = c + "abc" + c;

        assertTrue(Character.isWhitespace(c));
        assertEquals(s, s.trim());
        assertEquals("abc", s.strip());
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you also print the output.

Answer (score 29):

In general both method removes leading and trailing spaces from string. However the difference comes when we work with unicode charaters or multilingual features.

trim() removes all leading and trailing character **whose ASCII value is less than or equal to 32** (‘U+0020’ or space).

According to Unicode standards there are various space characters having ASCII value more than 32(‘U+0020’). Ex: 8193(U+2001).

To identify these space characters, new method isWhitespace(int) was added from Java 1.5 in Character class. This method uses unicode to identify space characters. You can read more about unicode space characters [here](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html).

New method strip which is added in java 11 **usage this Character.isWhitespace(int) method to cover wide range of white space characters** and remove them.

example

```
public class StringTrimVsStripTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = '\u2001'+"String    with    space"+ '\u2001';
        System.out.println("Before: \"" + string+"\"");
        System.out.println("After trim: \"" + string.trim()+"\"");
        System.out.println("After strip: \"" + string.strip()+"\"");
   }
}
```

Output

```
Before: "  String    with    space  "
After trim: " String    with    space "
After strip: "String    with    space"
```

**Note:** If you are running on windows machine, you may not be able to see the similar output due to limited unicode set. you can try some online compilers for testing this code.

Comment: How is it different from the other two answers?

Answer (score 7):

An example where `strip()` and `trim()` results in different output:

```java
String s = "test string\u205F";
String striped = s.strip();
System.out.printf("'%s'%n", striped);//'test string'

String trimmed = s.trim();
System.out.printf("'%s'%n", trimmed);//'test string '
```