# Difference between isEmpty() and isBlank() Method in java 11

Tags: java, string, is-empty, java-11

**Java 11** has added A new instance method  `isBlank()` to `java.lang.String` class.

What's the basic difference between the existing `isEmpty` and newly added `isBlank()` method?

Comment: Downvoted because the questions is somewhat arbitrary (`isempty` and `isBlank` pretty much tell you what the difference is) and easily answerable by looking at their Javadoc.

Comment: On the contrary to the ease of complexity. Would actually await someone to pitch in and speak about any difference(if) in the performance of the existing solution versus the `isBlank`, since the JDK link reads *"avoids any object construction..."* as well. :) Couldn't find the numbers on the link either.

Comment: Technically, the question deserves a down-vote for lack of research. But its one of those questions that are probably searched often and as long as theres no duplicate, well. So it probably is worth having it here on SO.

Comment: Upvoting because I just googled it and this was the first result.

Comment: Upvoting. The answer is not crystal clear, in particular for people who first language is not English.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**isEmpty()**

The java string `isEmpty()` method checks if this string is empty. It returns **true**, if the length of the string is 0 otherwise false **e.g.**

```
System.out.println("".isEmpty()); // Prints - True
System.out.println(" ".isEmpty()); //Prints - False
```

**[Java 11 - isBlank()](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8200437)**

The new instance method `java.lang.String.isBlank()` **returns true if the string is empty or contains only white space**, 
where whitespace is defined as any codepoint that returns true when passed to Character#isWhitespace(int).

```
boolean blank = string.isBlank();
```

---

**Before Java 11**

```
boolean blank = string.trim().isEmpty();
```

**After Java 11**

```
boolean blank = string.isBlank();
```

Comment: The **"Before Java 11"** and **"After Java 11"**-examples are not equivalent. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266582/difference-between-string-trim-and-strip-methods-in-java-11

Comment: Note that a null.isEmpty() throws an NPE.

Comment: Based on @MarkHu 's comment I prefer using apache.commons for such things for being able to automatically handle null values.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is as below :-

isBlank() returns true for the string having only white space characters whereas isEmpty() will return false for such strings.

```
("\n\r  ").isBlank();  //returns true
("\n\r  ").isEmpty();  //returns false
```

For detailed explanation with Code Example visit : [isBlank() vs isEmpty() in String class Java](https://techforhumans.site/java/general-java/isblank-vs-isempty-in-string-class-java/)

Answer (score 2):

Java 11 added has new method called `.isBlank()` in `String` class

1. `isBlank()` method is equal to `str.trim().isEmpty()` in earlier to java 11 versions
2. `isEmpty()` : Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0

This is the internal implementation of `isBlank()` method in `String` class of java 11

```
public boolean isBlank() {
    return indexOfNonWhitespace() == length();
}

private int indexOfNonWhitespace() {
    if (isLatin1()) {
        return StringLatin1.indexOfNonWhitespace(value);
    } else {
        return StringUTF16.indexOfNonWhitespace(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your statement that `isBlank()` is equal to `str.trim().isEmpty()` is wrong.  `trim()` does not take out unicode whitespace characters.  `strip()` and `isBlank()` do.

Answer (score 1):

### **When to use isNull, isEmpty, isBlank** **isNull()** **Checks if the  value is "null".**

```
isNull(null) = true
isNull("") = false
isNull(" ") = false
isNull("bob") = false
isNull(" bob ") = false
```

Returns true if the string is null.

### **isEmpty()** **Checks if the  value is an empty string containing no characters or whitespace.**

- 

```
isEmpty(null) = true
isEmpty("") = true
isEmpty(" ") = false
isEmpty("bob") = false
isEmpty(" bob ") = false
```

- 

Returns true if the string is null or empty.

**

### isBlank() Checks if the value is null, empty, or contains only whitespace characters.

**

*

```
isBlank(null) = true
isBlank("") = true
isBlank(" ") = true
isBlank("bob") = false
isBlank(" bob ") = false
```

- 

Returns true if the string is null, empty, or only whitespace.

Comment: You know what, I used isBlank() on null string which resulted into NPE.

Answer (score 0):

From **https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html**

[image]

In case you can't see the screenshot:

> boolean   isBlank() Returns true if the string is empty or contains only
> white space codepoints, otherwise false.
>
> boolean   isEmpty() Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0.