# Save a string from a list using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to stream a list of strings. I know we can do it like below:

```
list.stream().filter(i -> !Stringutils.isempty(service.someMethod(i))).map(i -> service.someMethod(i)).findfirst().get();
```

The problem is I need to call the `service.someMethod` twice.

Any suggestions here to avoid the `service.someMethod` calling it twice once in filter and another one for mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reverse map and filter as such:

```
list.stream() 
    .map(service::someMethod)
    .filter(s -> !Stringutils.isEmpty(s)) // or if it exists, StringUtils::isNotEmpty
    .findFirst()
    .get()
```

Comment: Or, if `someMethod` is never returning `null`, just `s -> !s.isEmpty()`. In fact, even if the method can return `null`, I’d rather use `s -> s !=null && !s.isEmpty()`, instead of adding a 3rd party library dependency that makes it unrecognizable if `null` handling is wanted or not.

Comment: I'm fine with your comment, but I was answering the question which used `Stringutils` (notice the lowercase `u`:)). I would personally use a method reference rather than a lambda, especially for common String related code, and if present, use common-lang3/4.

Answer (score 1):

I love working with java8 streams, hope you do too.

it seems that you want to map list with `someMethod` and then filter not-empty values, so just do this!
the only thing you should do is to change the order of map and filter.
after changing orders, someMethod will only be called once, because we map them once and filter the mapped values.

new code will be like this:

```java
 String answer = list
       .stream()
       .map(a -> service.someMethod(a))
       .filter(a -> !a.isEmpty())
       .findFirst()
       .get();
```

and better, you can replace lambda with method reference

```java
     .map(service::someMethod)
     // same as .map(a -> service.someMethod(a))
```

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Just to add a side note, make sure that to use ```isBlank()``` method if you use JDK 11
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299126/difference-between-isempty-and-isblank-method-in-java-11?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @parrotjack using `isBlank()` only makes sense, if the different semantic of `isBlank()` is actually intended. There is no indication here, that `isBlank()` is intended.

Comment: @Holger makes sense, but for safer side i just mentioned. No harm.