# Why is String.strip() 5 times faster than String.trim() for blank string In Java 11

Tags: java, string, performance, microbenchmark, java-11

I've encountered an interesting scenario. For some reason `strip()` against blank  string (contains whitespaces only) significantly faster than `trim()` in Java 11.

**Benchmark**

```
public class Test {

    public static final String TEST_STRING = "   "; // 3 whitespaces

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 200, timeUnit = MILLISECONDS)
    @Measurement(iterations = 20, time = 500, timeUnit = MILLISECONDS)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    public void testTrim() {
        TEST_STRING.trim();
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 200, timeUnit = MILLISECONDS)
    @Measurement(iterations = 20, time = 500, timeUnit = MILLISECONDS)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    public void testStrip() {
        TEST_STRING.strip();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

**Results**

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:04:16

Benchmark        Mode  Cnt           Score          Error  Units
Test.testStrip  thrpt  200  2067457963.295 ± 12353310.918  ops/s
Test.testTrim   thrpt  200   402307182.894 ±  4559641.554  ops/s
```

Apparently `strip()` outperforms `trim()` ~5 times.

Although for non-blank string, results are almost identical:

```
public class Test {

    public static final String TEST_STRING = " Test String ";

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 200, timeUnit = MILLISECONDS)
    @Measurement(iterations = 20, time = 500, timeUnit = MILLISECONDS)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    public void testTrim() {
        TEST_STRING.trim();
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 200, timeUnit = MILLISECONDS)
    @Measurement(iterations = 20, time = 500, timeUnit = MILLISECONDS)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    public void testStrip() {
        TEST_STRING.strip();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }
}


# Run complete. Total time: 00:04:16

Benchmark        Mode  Cnt          Score         Error  Units
Test.testStrip  thrpt  200  126939018.461 ± 1462665.695  ops/s
Test.testTrim   thrpt  200  141868439.680 ± 1243136.707  ops/s
```

How come? Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

---

**Testing environment**

- CPU - Intel Xeon E3-1585L v5 @3.00 GHz
- OS - Windows 7 SP 1 64-bit
- JVM - Oracle JDK 11.0.1
- Benchamrk - JMH v 1.19

---

### Update

Added more performance tests for different Strings (empty, blank, etc).

**Benchmark**

```
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = SECONDS)
@Fork(value = 3)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
public class Test {

    private static final String BLANK = "";              // Blank
    private static final String EMPTY = "   ";           // 3 spaces
    private static final String ASCII = "   abc    ";    // ASCII characters only
    private static final String UNICODE = "   абв    ";  // Russian Characters

    private static final String BIG = EMPTY.concat("Test".repeat(100)).concat(EMPTY);

    @Benchmark
    public void blankTrim() {
        BLANK.trim();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void blankStrip() {
        BLANK.strip();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void emptyTrim() {
        EMPTY.trim();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void emptyStrip() {
        EMPTY.strip();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void asciiTrim() {
        ASCII.trim();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void asciiStrip() {
        ASCII.strip();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void unicodeTrim() {
        UNICODE.trim();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void unicodeStrip() {
        UNICODE.strip();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void bigTrim() {
        BIG.trim();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void bigStrip() {
        BIG.strip();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

**Results**

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:05:23

Benchmark           Mode  Cnt           Score          Error  Units
Test.asciiStrip    thrpt   15   356846913.133 ±  4096617.178  ops/s
Test.asciiTrim     thrpt   15   371319467.629 ±  4396583.099  ops/s
Test.bigStrip      thrpt   15    29058105.304 ±  1909323.104  ops/s
Test.bigTrim       thrpt   15    28529199.298 ±  1794655.012  ops/s
Test.blankStrip    thrpt   15  1556405453.206 ± 67230630.036  ops/s
Test.blankTrim     thrpt   15  1587932109.069 ± 19457780.528  ops/s
Test.emptyStrip    thrpt   15  2126290275.733 ± 23402906.719  ops/s
Test.emptyTrim     thrpt   15   406354680.805 ± 14359067.902  ops/s
Test.unicodeStrip  thrpt   15    37320438.099 ±   399421.799  ops/s
Test.unicodeTrim   thrpt   15    88226653.577 ±  1628179.578  ops/s
```

Testing environment is the same.

Only one interesting finding. String which contains Unicode characters getting `trim()`'ed faster than `strip()`'ed

Comment: `strip()` is newer...(does not use `getChar` {unicode}, only checks trailing characters for empty strings, returns `""` {literal} instead of `new String(bytes)`)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On OpenJDK 11.0.1 `String.strip()` (actually `StringLatin1.strip()`) optimizes stripping to an empty `String` by returning an interned `String` constant:

```
public static String strip(byte[] value) {
    int left = indexOfNonWhitespace(value);
    if (left == value.length) {
        return "";
    }
```

while `String.trim()` (actually `StringLatin1.trim()`) always allocates a new `String` object. In your example `st = 3` and `len = 3` so

```
return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ?
        newString(value, st, len - st) : null;
```

will under the hood copy the array and creates a new `String` object

```
return new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(val, index, index + len),
                      LATIN1);
```

Making above assumption we can update the benchmark to compare against a non-empty `String` which shouldn't be affected by mentioned `String.strip()` optimization:

```
@Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 200, timeUnit = MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 20, time = 500, timeUnit = MILLISECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
public class MyBenchmark {

  public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "   "; // 3 whitespaces
  public static final String NOT_EMPTY_STRING = "  a "; // 3 whitespaces with a in the middle

  @Benchmark
  public void testEmptyTrim() {
    EMPTY_STRING.trim();
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void testEmptyStrip() {
    EMPTY_STRING.strip();
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void testNotEmptyTrim() {
    NOT_EMPTY_STRING.trim();
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void testNotEmptyStrip() {
    NOT_EMPTY_STRING.strip();
  }

}
```

Running it shows no significant difference between `strip()` and `trim()` for a non-empty `String`. Oddly enough trimming to an empty `String` is still the slowest:

```
Benchmark                       Mode  Cnt           Score           Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testEmptyStrip     thrpt  100  1887848947.416 ± 257906287.634  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testEmptyTrim      thrpt  100   206638996.217 ±  57952310.906  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testNotEmptyStrip  thrpt  100   399701777.916 ±   2429785.818  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testNotEmptyTrim   thrpt  100   385144724.856 ±   3928016.232  ops/s
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation! I'm kinda wondering why JDK developers did not optimize the `trim()` same way as `strip()` works. 5x is a huge performance difference.

Answer (score 9):

After looking into the source code of OpenJDK, assuming the implementation of the Oracle version is similar, I would imagine the difference is explained by the facts that

- `strip` will try to find the first non-whitespace character, and if none is found, simply returns `""`
- `trim` will always return a `new String(...the substring...)`

One could argue that `strip` is just a tiny bit more optimised than `trim`, at least in OpenJDK, because it dodges the creation of new object unless necessary.

(Note: I didn't take the trouble to check the unicode versions of these methods.)

Answer (score 1):

Yep. In Java 11 or earlier seems that .trim() is always creating a new String() but strip() is returning a cache String. You can test this simple code and prove it yourself.

```
public class JavaClass{
  public static void main(String[] args){
      //prints false
      System.out.println("     ".trim()=="");//CREATING A NEW STRING()
  }
}
```

vs

```
public class JavaClass{
  public static void main(String[] args){
      //prints true
      System.out.println("     ".strip()=="");//RETURNING CACHE ""
  }
}
```