# Comparison error when comparing a value from hashmap to a normal string

Tags: java, hashmap, equals

I have a string value stored in a variable called `userPassword`, which is what I got from the user using scanner. I also have a hashmap like this:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| username1 | password1 |
| username2 | password2 |
| username3 | password3 |

I have a variable `userPassword` with value `123`, and also a value in hashmap which is also `123`

```java
public class Authentication {
    public void verifyLogin(LoginDetailsPojo userLoginDetailsObj, Map<String,String> map){
    //Passing a object and hash map as parameters
        String userPassword = userLoginDetailsObj.password;
        System.out.println(userPassword);//Printing "123"
        String mapPassword = map.get(userLoginDetailsObj.userName);
        System.out.println(mapPassword); //Printing "123"
        if(userPassword.equals(mapPassword))
            System.out.println("it is equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Even though both the variables (`userPassword` and `mapPassword`) have the same value `123`, the `if` block is not executing

Comment: Do `System.out.println( ">" + userPassword + "<");` and same for `mapPassword` to ensure there is no leading space around

Answer (score 0):

try this, I have added trim() to delete any head or trail white spaces

```
public class Authentication {
    public void verifyLogin(LoginDetailsPojo userLoginDetailsObj, Map<String,String> map){
    //Passing a object and hash map as parameters
        String userPassword = userLoginDetailsObj.password;
        System.out.println(userPassword);//Printing "123"
        String mapPassword = map.get(userLoginDetailsObj.userName);
        System.out.println(mapPassword); //Printing "123"
        if(userPassword.trim().equals(mapPassword.trim()))
            System.out.println("it is equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `strip` instead of `trim` from java 11 onwards. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51266583/7804477)

Comment: Yes, I have already tried out .trim(),it does not work, strip() works fine tq