# Jackson ObjectMapper parses "null" as a valid JSON?

Tags: java, jackson

I recently learned that the following behavior is default:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    final MyClass aNull = objectMapper.readValue(" null", MyClass.class);
    // works and aNull == null

    final MyClass bNull = objectMapper.readValue((String) null, MyClass.class);
    // throws IllegalArugmentException
}

public static class MyClass {
    public String value;
}
```

I find this somewhat counterintuitive.

Is there a way to force a "strict" parsing and make the first example throw `IllegalArugmentException` (or any other exception)?

We want this because otherwise we need to do extensive input validation or wrap extend the `ObjectMapper` to override the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```java
var input =  // string input
var ob = objectMapper.readValue(input, MyClass.class);
return Optional.ofNullable(ob)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArugmentException("Invalid Input"));
```

Comment: That's definitely an option. We have hundreds of places where we would need to put this. In our case we do not want it to ever parse this as a valid input.

This is why I asked if there is away to set this through the Jackson configuration. Otherwise we would need to extend the `ObjectMapper` and override the behavior

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's not counterintuitive at all.

JSON is a data interchange format that uses text (aka a string). The string `"null"` is a perfectly valid JSON document that contains the single value `null`. Why should parsing a valid JSON document throw an exception?

When parsing the JSON `null` into a Java object, it would make sense to be represented as a Java `null` value. And I believe this is the only case you can get `null` here so if you want to catch this case you just need to compare the result to `null` (which you probably should be doing regardless).

To show that this is a value JSON document, you could try  `objectMapper.parseTree("null")` which will return an instance of [`NullNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/node/NullNode.html).

OTOH `objectMapper.readValue(null, MyClass.class)` makes no sense, since as JSON is a text format and `null` isn't a string (and casting won't make it a string), it can't be parsed as JSON, so the exception makes sense.

And input validation is always a good idea.

Comment: We are aware this is according to specification. This is a part of input validation. The input is a JSON string. We do basic validation that the parameter is supplied, but in the end we rely on parser to tell us if this is a valid object in our system. Coincidentally, nowhere in our system we consider input of text `{space}null` (and its permutations) as valid input. We are hoping that there is a flag for this similar to how flags for writing out `null` properties or strict parsing exist.

Answer (score 0):

String literals like " null" are valid JSON and there is no way for `objectMapper` to treat it differently AFAIK. Relying on `objectMapper` for input validation is not a good idea either.

Here is how you can achieve input validation cheaply (it definitly cheaper that running `objectMapper.readValue`):

```
 var value = // read input
 if(null == value || "null".equalsIgnoreCase(value.strip())) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException();
 }
```

**FYI**: `objectMapper` will throw `IllegalArgumentException` exception on `(String) null` parameter because of [_assertNotNull](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/e860795f8d8523ff71598bc30751efd62b87e6ed/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L3815)

Comment: In Java the `trim` method should be used. AFAIK `strip` does not exist.
https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Comment: `strip` since java 11

Comment: Did not notice that both `trim` & `strip` are now present.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266582/difference-between-string-trim-and-strip-methods-in-java-11