# This code throws an exception for the line Integer.parseInt(data[2])

Tags: java, integer, numberformatexception, parseint

In my `playerList.txt` I have lines constructed as such:

```
Nathaniel, Clyne, 12, first
```

Why can't it accept `Integer.parseInt`?

I have a class `MemberPlayer` that defines a `MemberPlayer` should have the first name, last name, age and team (first or second).

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
>   string: " 12"
>   at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString NumberFormatException.java:65)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:638)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
>   at FileHandler.getContent(FileHandler.java:53)
>   at Main.main(Main.java:55)

```
   public static final String FINAL_PATH = "playerList.txt";

   public static ArrayList<MemberPlayer> getContent(String FINAL_PATH)
     {
        ArrayList<MemberPlayer> list = new ArrayList<MemberPlayer>();
        try
        {
              Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(FINAL_PATH));
              while(sc.hasNextLine())
              {                                   
                    String data[] = sc.nextLine().split(",");
                    list.add(new MemberPlayer(data[0], data[1], 
                    Integer.parseInt(data[2]), data[3]));
              }

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {

        }
        return list;
   }
```

Comment: looks like you need to trim the leading blank from the string value `" 12"`.

Comment: [Converting a String with spaces to an Integer in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851668/converting-a-string-with-spaces-to-an-integer-in-java) (although I'd say you should be fixing your regex instead of doing this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`" 12"` can't be parsed into a valid `int` because it has a leading space, but `"12"` can:

```
Integer.parseInt(data[2].trim())
```

Make sure that all of `data[0]` ... `data[3]` exist before accessing them. The file might be corrupted or inaccurately filled.

Answer (score 1):

Try to split with ", " or ",\\s".

Comment: Better even `.split(",\\s*", 4)`.

Comment: Better yet - split on comma and trim before you use.