# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 ". Number format exception for "1". Although using trim() and split()

Tags: java

You are given an array A of N numbers, output the count of pairs in the array whose sum is divisible by 4.

The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases.

The description of T test cases follows.

The first line of each test case contains a single integer N.

The second line contains N space-separated integers

```
A[0] A[1] ... A[N−1]
```

representing the array numbers.

```java
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
    
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        //int t= scan.nextInt();
        while (t-- > 0) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            long ans=0;
            int[] arr= new int[n];
            String line = br.readLine();
            String[] strs = line.trim().split("\\s+");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
            }
            int[] count = new int[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                count[arr[i] % 4]++;
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
                ans += count[i] * count[4-i];
            }
            ans += (count[2] * (count[2]-1)) / 2;
            //System.out.println(ans);
            ans += (count[0] * (count[0]-1)) / 2;
            System.out.println(ans);                    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's an assignment. Not graded. I am able to do it with scanner. I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 " while using Buffered Reader

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 "
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
 at Main.main(Main.java:13)

Comment: There is a space after the `1`.  Can you see it in the exception message?  That's what is causing the exception.

Comment: Yes i saw that later. I was still wondering if it was coming from t,n or from arr[i].

Comment: Well the line numbers in the stacktrace will tell you that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did the right thing to `trim` when you read the array, but you didn't do it when you read `t` and `n` values.

Add `trim()` call in these lines:

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
```

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
```

[Converting a String with spaces to an Integer in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851668/converting-a-string-with-spaces-to-an-integer-in-java)

Also, if it is guaranteed that the numbers are separated by exactly one space, it is better to replace the string splitting with

```
String[] strs = line.trim().split(" ");
```

because splitting by one character is much faster than splitting by regex
[Java split String performances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001330/java-split-string-performances)