# A more modern way to trim whitespace in recent versions of Java

Tags: java, string, java-8, whitespace, java-9

Questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1437933/642706) discuss the limitations to the logic used by the [`String::trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) method. Some libraries [such as Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained) offer alternatives.

I vaguely recall that a recent version of Java (8, 9, 10) shipped with an alternative, a more modern [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)-savvy approach to defining and removing [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) from text.

Is there such a facility bundled with Java now?

Comment: @nullpointer Thanks, that was it, `String::strip` in Java 11.