# Java Regex replacement for negative bytes in string

Tags: java, regex

I'm getting a date from a web (html): " abril   2013  Viernes 19"

**I've tried all normal regex with no success.**

Finally I discovered the string bytes (str.getBytes()), and this are the values:

```
[-96, 97, 98, 114, 105, 108, -96, -96, -96, 50, 48, 49, 51, -96, -96, 86, 105, 101, 114, 110, 101, 115, -96, 49, 57]
```

**What are this -96?**

how to replace 1 or more -96 or whatever empty space is by 1 space?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Remove all spaces?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Why do you want to replace these negative bytes?

Comment: Why are you using a regex to parse a date? Have you tried [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Comment: Yes i need to rEplace all empty chars by 1 space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `Character.isSpaceChar` function to do this. As mentioned in [a response to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6255512/1427124), you can use it in a java regex like this:

```
String sampleString = "\u00A0abril\u00A0\u00A02013\u00A0Viernes\u00A019";
String result = sampleString.replaceAll("\\p{javaSpaceChar}", " ");
```

I think that will do exactly what you want while avoiding any need to deal with raw bytes.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks a lot! str.replaceAll("\\p{javaSpaceChar}+", " ").trim();

Answer (score 4):

The byte -96 (A0 in hexadecimal, or 160 as an unsigned byte), is the non-breaking space in the ISO-8859-1 character encoding, which is probably the encoding you used to transform the string to bytes.

Comment: @rgettman I think there's a serial downvoter in this thread. A bunch of my posts were downvoted, but then the system picked it up and reverted most of them.

Answer (score 4):

The first byte (-96) is negative because in Java bytes are signed.  It corresponds to character 160 (256 - 96), which is a [non-breaking space](http://www.ascii-code.com/).  You'll need to specify that character directly in your regular expression.

```
str = str.replaceAll(String.valueOf((char) -96), " ");
```

Comment: @rgettman When I first saw the answer, I thought it will work, but I've tried and **doesn't work**.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this way (please if anyone have a better answer I'll appreciate it):

```
byte[] b=str.getBytes();
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if (b[i]==-96)
        b[i]=" ".getBytes()[0];
}
String strOut=new String(b).trim();
Pattern blank=Pattern.compile("\\s+|\b+|\t+|\n+|\f+|\r+");
strOut=blank.matcher(strOut).replaceAll(" ");
```

Thanks every body for help!