# unable to replace blank space in String java

Tags: java, replaceall

bit of a weird one this as I have checked it over multiple times and still cannot see anything wrong with what I am doing.

Anyway, I have this string named score that is a method parameter. The input is `"0 - 2"`, I would like to parse this string but before I must remove the blank spaces. I've tried using `score = score.replaceAll("\\s+", "")` and `score = score.replace(" ", "")` however the blank spaces are still not replaced. Underneath this line of code I print out the score and it is still displaying the string as `"0 - 2"` with the spaces not deleted. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the code for the method

```
public static int parseScore(String score, boolean first){

    score = score.replaceAll("\\s+",""); // remove white space
    System.out.println(score);

    String[] tokens = score.split("-");

    if(first == true){

        return Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);

    }else{

        return Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);

    }

}
```

Error:

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0 "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at PredictResult2.parseScore(PredictResult2.java:32)
    at PredictResult2.main(PredictResult2.java:102)*

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that the string that I am using has already been parsed from a downloaded html page. Could that have anything to do with it? maybe different character formatting or something?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your debugger to see what is happening on each line?

Comment: System.out.println(score) returns "0 - 2". And therefore when the line return Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]) is executed it returns a NumberFormatException. I will edit in the actual error

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly fine. It works just fine when I tested it, so that's not it. It must be some other odd problem.

But anyways, for what you're trying to achieve maybe `trim()` would be more efficient and quicker.

```
    public static int parseScore(String score, boolean first){
    String[] tokens = score.split("-");
    if(first == true){
        return Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].trim());
    }else{
        return Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].trim());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a case of dealing with non-breaking spaces. Stumbled about these a while ago and wrote myself the following util method. More information is found here:

[Why is non-breaking space not a whitespace character in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060570/why-is-non-breaking-space-not-a-whitespace-character-in-java)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

```
/**
 * Trims non-breaking whitespace, too.
 */
public static String trim(String value) {
    return value.replaceAll("[\\s\\u00A0]+$", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input must be wrong. Your code works good - check this piece of code:

```
public static void parseScore(){

    String score = "0 - 2";
    score = score.replaceAll("\\s+","");

    System.out.println(score);

    String[] tokens = score.split("-");

    System.out.println(tokens[0]);
    System.out.println(tokens[1]);


    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]));
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    parseScore();
}
```

If you are not sure about the input I suggest converting the string to char array and printing the ASCII code of each character. Then compare the output with the table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

```
char[] array = score.toCharArray();
    for (char c : array)
        System.out.print((int)c + " ");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! Yeah I thought this may be the case. If you look at the edit I just made on the post I believe it may be to do with some unusual character formatting from the html page that i have ripped from the web.

Comment: 0 - 2 is the input. Or atleast that is what I copied from the output of the println function. I'll try the character array thing and get back to you anyway, thanks!

Comment: Here is the output from the char array: 48 160 45 160 50. ohhh okay, so space is actually being formatted as "á". So should I try to replace that character instead?

Comment: Yes, you should remove this strange letter from your string. Try this: http://pastebin.com/FU7j4x8E